# Java, thinks my variable is a package error (trying to make hashmap)

Tags: java, hashmap

I have even copy pasted examples of other people hashmaps and they gave the same error. Is there something really obviously stupid I've not seen here?

```
package hangman;
import java.util.*;
public class Dictionary 
{
    Map<String,String> myDictionary = new HashMap<String,String>();
    myDictionary.put("czxc","asdsad");
}
```

netbeans says package myDictionary does not exist,  expected, illegal start of type.

many thanks to anyone who can help

Comment: The `put()` statement should be in the constructor or in a method

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a constructor, i changed your code for you:

```
package hangman;
import java.util.*;
public class Dictionary {
     private Map<String,String> myDictionary = new HashMap<String,String>();

     public Dictionary(){
         myDictionary.put("czxc","asdsad");
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may achieve executable code with a minor change:

```
public class Dictionary {
    Map<String,String> myDictionary = new HashMap<String,String>() {{
        put("czxc","asdsad");
    }};
}
```

That syntax may appear "odd" if you haven't seen it before: it's an anonymous class with an initialiser block.